# Is vehicle "Auto Parts" & "Spare Parts" are same?

Tags: american-english, british-english

What the difference between auto parts and spare parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spare means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spare)

> not being used especially : held for emergency use 
>   *a spare tire*

The tires on the car are equally auto parts, since they are parts for an automobile, but the spare part is not used.

Comment: In other words, _spare parts_ are available to replace any part of the car which may develop a fault.

Comment: And *spare parts* could be for many things that have nothing to do with a car.